# increment the values of foreach within ifelse loop in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to increment the value of contents of foreach within ifelse loop. Would like to increment after i++ in the program (as shown below). Please guide me on how this can be done

```
foreach (var jagged in manager.JaggedList)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.Length; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < decimalNumbers.Length; j++)
                            {

                                foreach (var item in jagged.Items)
                                {
                                            if (intArray[i] == decimalNumbers[j])
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine(intArray[i]);
                                                if (i < intArray.Length)
                                                {
                                                    i++;
                                                    ****manager.jaggedlist increment****
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                 Console.WriteLine(0);
                                                }
                                            }
                                }
                            }

                      }
                   }
```

Comment: Approach 1: Use for loop instead of foreach and increment the iterator variable Approach 2: Move entire code in the foreach loop to a new function and call the function in the loop. Use return statement wherever you want to move to next iteration.

Comment: What is an if else loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have alot of loops, are you sure thats correct?
you can increment your manager.jaggedlist if you switch to a for loop for the most outer loop:

```
for (int m = 0; m < manager.JaggedList.Count; m++)
{
    var jagged = manager.JaggedList[m];

    // now you can do m++ and get the next item from manager.JaggedList
    m++;

    // dont forget another range check
    if (m < manager.JaggedList.Count)
        jagged = manager.JaggedList[m];
}
```

Comment: This give me error in the next foreach loop @ foreach (var item in jagged.Items)...."The name 'jagged' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: This does `m++` twice per loop, is that OK?